# PHP - Call to undefined function http_inflate()

Tags: php, http, function, undefined, inflate

i am trying to create a module that makes a call to the [stackexchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) which returns a gzipencoded or a deflated Json response. to decompress it i am using the method [http_inflate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-inflate.php) but i am getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function http_inflate()
```

Is this method dependent on any library or extension?

I am running PHP 5.3.13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the HTTP extension, as seen in the link below:

[PHP.net: Installing the HTTP plugin](http://php.net/manual/fa/http.install.php)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, in that case is there anyway we can bundle it with the module so that if someone installs the module, i can make sure that they have it installed and if not then install it and activate the module ?

Comment: thanks all of you, though i'd have to give to David as he was the first one :p

Comment: Link is dead (gives 404); please provide original instructions.

Answer (score 3):

[http_inflate](http://www.php.net/http_inflate) is not bundled with PHP. It is part of the [HTTP library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.http.php). [See this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/http.install.php) for instructions on how to install it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, in that case is there anyway we can bundle it with the module so that if someone installs the module, i can make sure that they have it installed and if not then install it and activate the module ?

Comment: I don't think so, you could ask a seperate question for that after looking at the [PECL website](http://pecl.php.net/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to install an extension (**pecl_http**).  See [here on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/http.install.php) for information.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, in that case is there anyway we can bundle it with the module so that if someone installs the module, i can make sure that they have it installed and if not then install it and activate the module ?